# Suitable library/tool for work orchestration / task load balancing in a distributed system

Tags: c#, .net, distributed-system

I'm looking for a library / tool to help with work division.

Not just producer /consumer - queues won't work here - the work is long running, and needs to automatically load balance.

Imagine you have 100 items that need constant servicing - so long running code needs to operate on each item, e.g. constantly pushing content to 100 different http endpoints.

You have 5 machines running your code, and you ideally want each machine to handle 20 of those items in this example.

If a machine were to fail and then each of the remaining machines should take up the slack (ideally evenly - 25 in this example), so that each of those items is still serviced.

When that machine comes back up, the load is evenly distributed again.

Same for adding a new machine.

So essentially I want them all to compete for leases on these items, and those leases to automatically expire if the machine fails, and other nodes to see this and react accordingly.  And also to notice the other machine has insufficient work, and to give up leases.

I appreciate that K8S and similar perform these sorts of things, but for this system, cannot adopt that, and seek something simpler.  This could all be achieved through a database table, and smart client logic.   I just would rather not reinvent the wheel on this.

The workers are written in c#

Answer (score 0):

Put the work items into a (relational) database and have long running workers running on all available machines. Let them query for the next due work item, while locking them (select ... for update). Depending on how long the work on an item usually lasts, you might need to release the lock on the row and employ something like a lock table.

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't address auto-(re)balancing.

Comment: Yes, it does. If all nodes are eligible to execute all work items. If a node dies, the others will grab their work. If you add nodes, they will share the work as well.